# Get dynamically created asp control ids(values) using for loop

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How can I access the similar asp control id's by using **for** loop?
I have the following asp text boxes.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and I want to access all these text box value through for loop using jQuery, how can I do?

I am tried to get the value by below code, but it shows error.

```
var ar_val=[];
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
{
  var txtv = $("#<%=PFtxtname"+i+".ClientID%>").val().trim();
  ar_val.push(txtv);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing client side and server side code, it will not work this way.

add a commom css class to textboxes :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname1" runat="server" CssClass="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
```

and iterate on elements in Jquery using class selector:

```
$(".txtName").each(function() {

    alert($(this).val()) // for value
    alert(this.id)   // for id

})
```

Comment: Just a question: what if the jquery code is inside the markup file? Mixing code is still unhealthy, however, it should work then.

Comment: Yes we can write Jquery code in markup file inside script tag, better way is to use a separate js file,  and i was talking about OP using c# statements inside Jquery/javascript

Comment: It is certainly better to separate the code, BUT if the script is inside the markup, then you can use C# code there if I am not mistaken. At least you can do this with PHP. I do not remember how it was in C#, since I did not work with the language for a long time, but it would not make sense to not have this possibility.

Comment: We can use to some extent,  server side values are evaluated on page load, you cannot do like above to use javascript for loop and execute c# statements as c# code gets executed on page load while in js that's not the case

Comment: So we are in agreement that mixing client-side with server-side can work if the script is inside the markup, yet server-side code is executed before the page is sent to the client. I believe you should edit your answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad I am modified the old code, there they give the value directly(like ct100_...), but now i need change it to $("#<=....ClientID%>")

Comment: what you want now, i didnt got you?

Answer (score 0):

you should try this i think its working fine

```
var ar_val=[]; 
    $("form").find("[id$='PFtxtname']").each(function () {

            var txtv =  $(this).val().trim();  
    ar_val.push(txtv);    
                });
```